# Yii REST API - using multiple joins in query

Tags: php, mysql, rest, yii2

I have a yii app with a rest api. I want to get a post object complete with all comments for that post as well as the user object for the creator of the post.
Also in the comments I want the user object for each user who left a comment.

So one post with post user and many comments each with user.

The post controller serving the api request looks like this:

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $post = Post::find()
            ->joinWith('user)
            ->joinWith('comments')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
    }
    return $post;
```

Then the models for user and comment:

```
public function getUser()
{
  return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'created_by'])->innerJoinWith('profile p1');
}

public function getComments()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['object_id' => 'id'])->leftJoin('user u2', 'u2.id = comment.created_by');
}
```

The user for the post returns fine. The comments are returned. But there is no returned user for each comment. I feel like the left join in the getComments() method should pull in the user. What's missing?

I get back something like this:

```
{
"id":"1",
"message":"this is a post",
"user":
  [{
    "id:11",
    "name":"bob smith"
  }],
"comments":
  [{
    "id:21",
    "remark":"this is a comment"
  }]
}
```

and I want to get back this:

```
{
"id":"1",
"message":"this is a post",
"user":
  [{
    "id:11",
    "name":"bob smith"
  }],
"comments":
  [{
    "id:21",
    "remark":"this is a comment",
    "user":
      [{
        "id:41",
        "name":"jane doe"
      }]
  }]
}
```

**UPDATE**: If I change `getComments()` from `leftJoin` to `innerJoinWith` like this:

```
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['object_id' => 'id'])->innerJoinWith('user u2', 'u2.id = comment.created_by');
}
```

...then I get the properly formatted output BUT it only includes posts that contain comments.

Comment: It's actually wrong from my point of view. Please read this - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html Read about expand part and extraFields.

Comment: @ineersa I read that ...not sure how to implement that.  I added some code the the question if you could check.

Comment: That's kinda not so easy to get it right, simply use `with()` instead of `joinWith()` in your controller action, then add `user` and `comments` to `extraFields`, then use link with `expand=user,comments` to your action. In `getComments()` try to eager load data with `joinWith()`. Should do the trick.

Comment: @ineersa not sure how to do this. I have user with post, and also user with comments. Would you be able to answer with some code?

Answer (score 2):

I have not checked, but you could try:

```
$post = Post::find()
        ->joinWith('user')
        ->joinWith(['comments' => function($q) {
             $q->joinWith(['user']);
        }])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
}
```

Comment: This will only return posts that have comments.

Comment: Have you tried? joinWith produces a left join so it seems strange that it returns only post with comments.

Comment: I tried but Active Record `joinWith` is an inner join, [not a left join](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#relational-query).

Comment: Check documentation at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail  ... last parameter 'joinType' is LEFT JOIN, by default.